# ErrorException Array to string conversion Laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my code in the controller.
I want multiple data to insert into a database but I have a problem with Array:

```
public function postCreate(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $lastid = Tr_header::create($data)->id;
    if (count($request->id_product) > 0)
    {
        foreach($request->id_product as $item => $value)
        $datax = array(
            'id_tr_header' => $lastid,
            'id_product' => $request->id_product[$item],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$item],
            'date_kembali' => $request->date_kembali[$item],
            'information' => $request->information[$item],
        );
        Tr_detail::insert($datax);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple row at a time try this:

```
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $lastid = Tr_header::create($data)->id;
    if (count($request->id_product) > 0)
    {
        $datax = [];
        foreach($request->id_product as $item => $value)
         array_push($datax ,[
            'id_tr_header' => $lastid,
            'id_product' => $request->id_product[$item],
            'qty' => $request->qty[$item],
            'date_kembali' => $request->date_kembali[$item],
            'information' => $request->information[$item],
        ]);
        Tr_detail::insert($datax);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting your `$datax` variable, you need to create an array of arrays to pass on to your `insert()` function:

```
   public function postCreate(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $lastid = Tr_header::create($data)->id;
        if (count($request->id_product) > 0) {
            $datax = [];
            foreach ($request->id_product as $item => $value)
                $datax[] = array(
                    'id_tr_header' => $lastid,
                    'id_product' => $request->id_product[$item],
                    'qty' => $request->qty[$item],
                    'date_kembali' => $request->date_kembali[$item],
                    'information' => $request->information[$item],
                );
            Tr_detail::insert($datax);
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```